# r spatial join-multiple criteria

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, r-sf

I have two sf datasets and I want to find the 10 closest neighbors, based not only on distance but also on mathcing another column.
For example:

```
a = st_sf(a = 1:3, DD=c("d1","d2","d3"),
 geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))
b = st_sf(a = 11:14,DD=c("d1","d2","d2"),
 geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(10,10)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))
```

I would like to find the neighbors of "a" in "b" having the same value for "DD" col.
Currently I am using this [approach](https://github.com/michaeldorman/nngeo) based on `sf` and `nngeo`:

```
st_join(a, b, join = st_nn, k = 1, progress = FALSE)
```

But this joins points based on geometry only and I do not know how to get DD into account as well.

Thank you!

I have posted the question also on [gis.spatexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424098/r-spatial-join-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to fully understand, but I give it a try! So, please find below one possible solution using only the `sf` library and some `base R` functions.

The "strategy" is to transform the `dataframes` `a` and `b` into lists of `dataframes` according to the `DD` column (cf. the `base R` function `split()`) and then, to perform joins between the `dataframe` for each `DD` using the function `sf::st_join()` and its argument `join = st_nearest_feature`. Finally, the last operation is to convert the list of results of the different joins into a `dataframe` using the `base R` function `rbind()`.

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(sf)

a <- a[a$DD %in% b$DD,] # added following the OP's comment
b <- b[b$DD %in% a$DD,] # added following the OP's comment

a_list <- split(a, a$DD)
b_list <- split(b, b$DD)

result <- do.call(rbind,Map(st_join, a_list, b_list, MoreArgs = list(join = st_nearest_feature)))
```

- Output

```r
result
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> CRS:           NA
#>    a.x DD.x a.y DD.y        geom
#> d1   1   d1  11   d1 POINT (1 1)
#> d2   2   d2  12   d2 POINT (2 2)
#> d3   3   d3  14   d3 POINT (3 3)
```

- Data

  *NB: I added `"d3"` in `b`*

```r
a = st_sf(a = 1:3, DD=c("d1","d2","d3"),
          geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(1,1)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))
b = st_sf(a = 11:14,
          DD=c("d1","d2","d2","d3"),geom = st_sfc(st_point(c(10,10)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(2,2)), st_point(c(3,3))))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you @lovalery! I suppose that DD column should have the same levels present in both datasets? In my real data, this is not the case. Do you think this can be resolved?

Comment: @tzema, you are welcome. Please find above my edit: I added two lines of code at the beginning to be certain that the categories in the DD column of the `dataframe` `a` are found in `b` and vice versa. Cheers.